# Plotly: autorescaling y axis range when range slider used

Tags: plotly, autoscaling, yaxis

After a long search, I could not find any thread/discussion helping me to make **autoscaling** work with plotly.

The idea would be that when I use the x-range slider to go through the data, the y-axis would be dynamically rescaled each time I move the slider.

Currently, this is how it looks like (pretty unuseful):
[image]

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
    
    # Layout format and buttons
    layout = dict(
        xaxis=dict(
            rangeselector=dict(
                buttons=list([
                    dict(count=1,
                         label='1m',
                         step='month',
                         stepmode='backward'),
                    dict(count=6,
                         label='6m',
                         step='month',
                         stepmode='backward'),
                    dict(count=1,
                        label='YTD',
                        step='year',
                        stepmode='todate'),
                    dict(count=1,
                        label='1y',
                        step='year',
                        stepmode='backward'),
                    dict(step='all')
                ])
            ),
            rangeslider=dict(
                visible = True
            ),
            type='date'
        )
    )
    
    # Plot open, high, low, close for each coins
    for c in dic.keys():
        ohlc = dic[c][['open','high','low','close']].copy()
        
        candlestick = go.Candlestick(x = ohlc.index,
                                     open = ohlc['open'],
                                     high = ohlc['high'],
                                     low = ohlc['low'],
                                     close = ohlc['close'],
                                     name = 'OHLC')
        
        fig = go.Figure(data = [candlestick],
                        layout = layout)
        
        fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=True, 
                          zeroline=False, 
                          showticklabels=True,
                          showspikes=True, 
                          spikemode='across', 
                          spikesnap='cursor', 
                          spikethickness=1, 
                          showline=True, 
                          spikedash='dot',
                          spikecolor="#707070",
                          autorange = True,     # DOESN'T WORK....
                          fixedrange= False     # DOESN'T WORK....
                          )
            
        fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=True, 
                          zeroline=False, 
                          showticklabels=True,
                          showspikes=True, 
                          spikemode='across', 
                          spikesnap='cursor', 
                          spikethickness=1, 
                          showline=True, 
                          spikedash='dot',
                          spikecolor="#707070",
                          type='date',
                          )
        
        fig.update_layout(title = 'OHLC for: '+c,
                          height = 750,
                          plot_bgcolor="#FFFFFF",
                          hovermode="x",
                          hoverdistance=100,
                          spikedistance=1000,
                          xaxis_rangeslider_visible=True,
                          dragmode='pan',
                          )
        
        fig.show()
```

I tried to use `autorange = True` and `fixedrange = False` but apparently that does nothing for reasons I don't understand.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: As far as I know the only of achieving this behavior is using Dash. The furthest you can get with Plotly only is to be able to manually zoom in and scale the y axis that way Are you open to use Dash? https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/932

Comment: @plonfat yes to what @Brener Ramos wrote. if you would be interested in a `Plotly Dash` based solution, I would be happy to write one up for you

Comment: Hi all, sure I would be interested in any solution. Because right now its litterally unusable.... 

I never used Plotly Dash, is the structure completely different ?

Comment: Was any progress made with this? I am having the same issues now.